# What are the 7 cuts made in the Indian version of Deadpool?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, alternate-version, content-rating, deadpool

As per [bollywoodhungama.com](http://www.bollywoodhungama.com/news/17367188/Banned-in-China-Deadpool-passed-in-India-with-7-cuts), Deadpool passed CBFC-A rating with 7 cuts.

What are those exact 7 cuts made in Deadpool to get an A (Adult) rating from the CBFC (Central Board of Film Certification) of India? And how do they affect the film?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [businessofcinema.com](https://businessofcinema.com/hollywood/ryan-reynolds-deadpool-gets-censored-in-india-fans-lash-out/286550), seven scenes that were cut by the censorboard of India are:

> 1. All the cuss words have been muted. Also, some sexual euphemisms have been muted.
> 2. The triple headshot (with a deagle) scene has been zoomed to show only Deadpool. Because it shows violence.
> 3. All the nude and love-making scenes have been deleted and some have been shortened.
> 4. Hand cutting and gushing of blood of Deadpool has been replaced with the visuals of Stefan Kapicic’s character Colossus.
> 5. The bare bodies in the strip club have been replaced.
> 6. The lady in poster touching her parts is replaced.
> 7. All the gory shots in the climax scene are replaced too.

Below is the official paper of the cuts made in film,

[image]

After watching the film, I can say nothing will be missed from the story point of view, all the curse words are mute but rest is ok.