# Deadpool uncensored in Sweden?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, content-rating, deadpool

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_(film)#Outside_North_America) states that

> with records set for the biggest February and R-rated openings in numerous markets including Hong Kong, Taiwan, the Netherlands, Sweden, France, and the U.K

Implying that Deadpool is r-rated in Sweden. However, on my [local cinema](http://www.sf.se/biljetter/bokningsflodet/valj-forestallning/), I found that is it from 15 years onwards:

> Deadpool
>   1 timme 48 minuter , Från 15 år
>   Action, Äventyr, Science-Fiction

In Sweden, the movie appears (as most of movies) in original language with sub-titles, so I'm wondering if it is possible that different cinemas have different English versions (and hence some of them have it r-rated), or whether either source (my cinema, or wikipedia) have it wrong.

Comment: Just for your information - in some countries nobody will restrict children to go to the cinema alone, and R, or 18+ rating does not matter. In Latvia was Magic Mike XXL with champagne for free for ladies, and NOBODY asking for ID, so DEFINITELY some girls under 18 got the champagne - nobody cares.

Comment: Given the amount of violence and nudity in that movie, it would be kinda silly to be censoring it for language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Different countries have different boards who classify movies and assign ratings, often with different criteria for determining which rating it should receive and sometimes requiring scenes to be cut or otherwise modified to allow the film to receive a rating at all. See, for example, [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47693/what-are-the-7-cuts-made-in-indian-version-of-deadpool) about the cuts made to Deadpool to make it suitable for showing in India.

To make matters even more complicated, there's no universal system of ratings, so an R-rated movie in the US isn't going to have an R rating in the UK (because no such rating exists). Fortunately, the Wikipedia page on Motion picture rating system has a handy [comparison table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_picture_rating_system#Comparison_table).

From that you can see that the US R rating roughly corresponds to the Swedish "Not approved" rating, which is suitable for viewers aged 15 and above. The section on [Sweden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_picture_rating_system#Sweden) further down the page seems to back this up, and suggests that "Not approved" (for children) is the same thing as "15", which is the highest rating given.

With all that information, I'd assume that you'll see the uncensored cinematic release of Deadpool in Sweden (i.e. the same version that was released under an R rating in the US). As additional, anecdotal evidence, Deadpool has a 15 rating in the UK too, and having seen the film I can't imagine there's anything that was removed from the US R-rated version, since it contains a LOT of violence, blood, nudity and strong language.

Comment: Having found someone who is knowledgeable in these things, he confirmed that "Texas chain saw massacre was the last movie with  censorship that the public opinion was aware of"