# Did Deadpool 2 get censored in India too and to what extent?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, censorship, deadpool-2

When *Deadpool* was released in India it got heavily censored even for "A" rated version, and this is discussed in a [similar question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47693/what-are-the-7-cuts-made-in-the-indian-version-of-deadpool). But, what about the recently released sequel, *Deadpool 2* -- did it also face the same and to what extent did it get censored?

Comment: All the cuss words were taken away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that CBFC of India didn't cut any scenes, but beeped a few cuss words.

From [International Business Times](https://www.ibtimes.co.in/deadpool-2-youll-be-shocked-how-many-cuts-cbfc-ordered-ryan-reynolds-starrer-769300),

> When such has been the case in the past, you'd expect the foul-mouthed merc aka Deadpool to have a bumpy ride to the post-credits scenes. **However, CBFC has decided to let Marvel fans enjoy the summer by ordering zero cuts in Deadpool 2.**
>
> "**Deadpool 2 has got no cuts as such. A few words have been beeped out and nothing else. All the scenes have been retained, giving the viewers a better experience.**"
>
> The cuss words have been censored in a way that doesn't hinder the viewing experience. This comes as a great news and hints that there is finally some freedom of expression at the cinema.

From [NDTV](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/entertainment/reviews/deadpool-2-review-india-ryan-reynolds-1853081),

> Thankfully, the film isn't made worse in India by the CBFC (or the censor board, as it's often called). In the face of everyone's expectations – including this critic – **Deadpool 2 is nowhere as badly censored in India as the first one, which is great. The first non-muted delivery of the f-word was greeted with shock and surprise at the premiere screening, and the film also keeps much of its gore and violence, with very few noticeable cases of things being blurred or outright cuts.** That audiences in India can enjoy an A-rated movie on the big screen the way it's meant to be seen is rare indeed.